# Cannot get sql request from Query object?

Tags: query, sql

```
$qry = new WP_Query(array(
      'post_type' => $this->type,
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'meta_query' => array(
        array(
          'key' => "_{$this->metaPrefix}_name",
          'value' => $style['name'],
          'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
          'key' => "_{$this->metaPrefix}_created",
          'value' => $year,
          'compare' => '='
        )
      )
    ));
print_r($qry->request); die;
```

I am getting an empty string, is there a way to get something? Is there maybe a tool or something along that line or is this an expected behavior and I can do something to output the sql?

Comment: Without knowing where this is called from or when it's difficult to know what's going on.  Have you tried dumping $qry itself?

Comment: I didn't, but I thought it didn't matter where I was calling it from if I tried to print it immediately after the query object was instantiated. Am I wrong?

Comment: You might be executing that code in a place where WP_Query isn't available.  Are you in a page template?  Try dumping the entire $qry and see what's there.  I usually use something like `error_log( print_r( $your_var, true ) );` which will print to the PHP error log instead of the screen.  You can keep an eye on that during dev with a `tail -f /path/to/your/logfile`

Comment: I am in a plugin executed by a cronjob, maybe it's not available, because inside a php file rendering the page I am able to do it.